# Reference request for blocking sets in graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a DAG and $S$ be a subset of $V$. I will call $S$ $k$-blocking if on every path of length $k~$ there is at least one node from $S$.

This parameter sounds reasonable enough, so I believe it has been studied. If someone can tell me the right name of it or a relevant reference, I would much appreciate it.